# Start and stop Kubernetes on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes

How do you restart Kubernetes on Azure manually?

According to this article, it's possible to restart either using Azure Portal or Azure CLI but I don't see any options for this in the portal or from the az aks documentation.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#are-security-updates-applied-to-aks-agent-nodes

> "You have several options for rebooting nodes: 
>   Manually, through the Azure portal or the Azure CLI."

How do you reboot manually, either through portal or cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can restart the worker nodes. Those worker nodes are shown in the VMs if you use VMs for deployment or we can restart the VMSS if you deployed workers as VMSS